# Finding $\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\sin((2m+1)w)}{\sin\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)}$ where $0\le w\le 2\pi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, limits, trigonometry

> What could be the limit of $$\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\sin((2m+1)w)}{\sin\left(\frac{w}{2}\right)}\,,$$
>   where $ 0 \leq w \leq 2\pi$ ?

I tried using Matlab to see how the plot behave by giving different values for $m$. I noticed that plot becomes flat in zero when $m$ becomes very large.

At the beginning I computed $f(w)= \sum\limits_{\substack{k=-m}}^{m}{e^{ikw}} $ which gives the expression above and see if I can say something when $m$ goes to infinity.

Any suggestions or hint are welcomed.

Comment: How does $x$ relate to $w$?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, you are considering the right limit? You can write
$$ \frac{\sin (2m+1)w}{\sin w/2}
=\sin (2mw) \frac{\cos w}{\sin w/2} + \cos (2mw) \frac{\sin w}{\sin w/2}\,, $$
and one can see that the limit $m\to \infty$ does not exist.

The situation is better, when you consider
$$ \lim_{w\to 0} \frac{\sin (2m+1)w}{\sin w/2}\,,
$$
which you can calculate using de l'Hopital,
$$ \lim_{w\to 0} \frac{\sin (2m+1)w}{\sin w/2}
= \lim_{w \to 0} \frac{ (2m+1)\cos (2m+1)w}{\frac 12 \cos w/2}
= m+\frac 12\,.$$

Comment: Yes I am interested on the limit when $m$ grows larger but I was expecting your answer because $\sum\limits_{\substack{k=-\infty}}^{\infty}{e^{ikw}}$ does not exist.

Comment: Then the limit does not exist, except for $w=\pi$.The limit for $\sin (2mw)$ and $\cos (2mw)$ would also exist for $w \in \{0, 2\pi\}$, but in that case $\sin w/2 = 0$ and the sequence in undefined.

Comment: yes, thank you .